# What are all the solutions for this equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Suppose that I have an image with $n$ pixels and the following equation,

$$\sum_{r \in P} (U(r) - \sum_{s \in N(r)}w_{rs}U(s))^2 = 0 $$

where:

$U = (U(1), U(2),..., U(n))$ are the variables;

$P$ is the set of all the $n$ pixels;

$N(r)$ is the set of all neighboring pixels of $r$. 
For example, for an image with 3x3 pixels, $N(1) = \text{{2, 4, 5}}$

$w_{rs}$ is a weighting function where $ \sum_{s \in N(r)}w_{rs} = 1$.

*Note:* I just mentioned that it is an image to better explain the role of the set $N$ and the function $w_{rs}$.

Well, it's easy to show that "one" solution for that equation are the scalar multiples of the all-ones vector. I mean, $U = k\cdot(1, 1, ..., 1)$ is clearly a solution.

My question is: there's a way to proof that this is the **"only"** solution for the above equation? Or there're other ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.  Suppose you have a solution that is not constant.  Then the maximum of the solution occurs at (at least one) location $s$, with a strictly smaller value in (at least one) neighbor.  Can you get a contradiction?  You can if the weights are all positive, but not in general.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the right way: suppose a non-constant solution and get a contradiction. But I didn't understand your idea. Can you explain it in more detail, please?

Comment: Actually it's a contradiction if all the weights are strictly positive, right?

Comment: It's a contradiction if $w_{rs} \ne 0$, for some $r,s$, where $r$ is a point where $U$ is the maximum, and $s$ is a neighboring point where $U$ is not the maximum.  (Actually, I also assume $w_{rs} \ge 0$ for all $r,s$, which may be intended in "weighting function".)

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your attention. You helped me a lot. =)